# How do I run a command with string formatting?

Tags: python, command, string-formatting

I am using the subprocess module to run a command in python.  But the problem is that I also want to include a  string (for a file name) in the command.

An example of what I want to do:

```
  from subprocess import call

  command = "cd/DirectoryName"

  call = [(command)]
```

In this specific example I want DirectoryName to be a variable determined by the user.

What I have tried to no avail:

```
  Desktop=raw_input()
  cmd="'cd %s'(Desktop/)"
  call([cmd])
```

Here's the error I get when I try to run these commands in the python shell.

```
    Chicken='Chicken'
    command = 'say %s' % (Chicken)
    print command
    say Chicken
    call([command])

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Applications/WingIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 1,     in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
    File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Just tried this and it made the shell crash.

```
    Chicken="Chicken"
    print Chicken
    Chicken
    call[("say %s" % (Chicken)]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how string interpolation works.

```
cmd='cd %s' % (Desktop,)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with the syntax.  I updated the question though with the error I get.  I don't see how the file or directory would effect the command I wanted to execute.

Comment: Simple. There is no command by the name of "cd <whatever>". There is a "cd" command, but that's not what you're executing.

Comment: But in the example I posted, say makes the computer speak the word.  Like it should have said 'Chicken' when I executed the call statement.

Comment: The example you posted runs `"say Chicken"`, not `"say" "Chicken"`.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand how the call function works.  What is the difference between these two?

Comment: One runs the command "say Chicken". The other runs the command "say" and passes "Chicken" as an argument.

Comment: Actually, the `cd` you normally run is a shell builtin. Some systems have a `cd` executable, but it doesn't do anything useful as far as I know. (Changing a subprocess's working directory does not affect the parent process.) So just fixing the invocation of call won't actually help, in this case...

Answer (score 0):

First off,

```
cmd="'cd %s'(Desktop/)"
```

Doesn't seem like it would "printf" the %s.

Maybe

```
cmd="'cd %s/'%(Desktop)"
```

But I still don't know if that will interpolate since it's inside a string can using the "call" function and a python command -- wouldn't that call it on the command line?